# Using font-awesome CDN with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, tampermonkey, userscripts

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Name
// @description  Description
// @author       You
// @version      0.1
// @match        https://mysite*
// @resource     customCSS https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// @grant        GM_getResourceText
// ==/UserScript==
//--- The @grant directive is used to restore the proper sandbox.

var newCSS = GM_getResourceText ("customCSS");
GM_addStyle (newCSS);

$("#somediv").before ( `
<div style="
    background-color: white;
    height: 150px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
">Test
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
</div>` );
```

I can see Bootstrap is working and also my div is showing but I can never make font-awesome work. Tried different versions, but still. I am familiar with font-awesome and have been using the kit for some time but cannot make this work using Tampermonkey. Any suggestions?

After some modifications I am seeing a square instead of the icon:

[image]

Comment: I believe font awesome allows kits to be limited to specific domains, is that kit authorised for use on the domain that this script runs on?

Comment: I don't see any limitation while checking the kit configuration, but I am ok to drop the kit and use CDN, was just my trying to achieve the solution somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Though the CSS files are fetched with `@resource`, the styles aren't applied. You need to use [`GM_getResourceText`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_getResourceText) and [`GM_addStyle`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_addStyle). See: [Tampermonkey's docs](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:resource) on how to correctly use `@resource` in the userscript header.

Comment: Thanks, got some progress, script is updated on the post but now I am seeing a default square instead of the icon, still not sure what I am missing, any further help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok, So I just add the following on the HTML render part and it is working now:

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>